# Populating table with data from a list asp.net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've been working on a .net Web API, my method returns an "EmployeeList" containing one or several Employees. The method takes a string as an in parameter (Employee name). The method is working perfectly fine and now I would like to consume my Webservice and fill a simple table in index.cshtml with the data from the returned EmployeeList.

Employeeclass:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Lastname { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
public decimal Salary { get; set; }
public DateTime Hired_Date { get; set; }
public string Note { get; set; }
```

And then the EmployeeList

```
public EmployeeList() { Catalog = new List<Employee>(); }
[XmlElement("Catalog")]
public List<Employee> Catalog {get; set;}
```

Finally my method in EmployeeController, returning an EmployeeList

```
        public EmployeeList GetEmployeeByName(string employeeName)
        {
        EmployeeList employeeList = new EmployeeList();
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(employeeXmlPath);
        foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("employee"))
        {
            Employee e = new Employee();
            if (employeeName != null)
            {
                if (element.Element("name").Value.ToLower().Contains(employeeName.ToLower()))
                {
                    e.Name = element.Element("name").Value;
                    e.Lastname = element.Element("lastname").Value;
                    e.Title = element.Element("title").Value;
                    e.Salary = Convert.ToDecimal(element.Element("salary").Value);
                    e.Hired_Date = Convert.ToDateTime(element.Element("hired_date").Value);
                    e.Note = element.Element("note").Value;

                    employeeList.Catalog.Add(e);
                }
            }
        }
        return employeeList;
    }
```

Now I would like to fill a table in index.cshtml with the data from "employeeList". How can I do this? I have no clue and I've been trying for a while. I've managed to create a search button, a textfield and a table. But then?

```
                <h5>Search for an Employee:</h5>
                <input type="text" id="employeeName" size="5" />
                <input type="button" value="Search" />

                <table id="employee" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1" width="915">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background-color: gray; color: white">Name</td>
                        <td style="background-color: gray; color: white">Lastname</td>
                        <td style="background-color: gray; color: white">Title</td>
                        <td style="background-color: gray; color: white">Salary</td>
                        <td style="background-color: gray; color: white">Hired Date</td>
                        <td style="background-color: gray; color: white">Note</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

All help is extremely appreciated. Been stuck on this for a while and I'm not doing any progress. How hard can it be? I just want to show the data from the employeeList in a table!

I'm off for a couple of hours now, but I'm looking forward to your responses.

Cheers guys/girls.

Comment: have you tried to use the `Dataset or DataTable` LoadFromXML` method and bind the data set to a DataGrid.. I think that would be much easier and it's not difficult to do..[Loading a DataSet from XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx29c3yd(v=vs.110).aspx) just one of many examples

Comment: Please show us how you're retrieving data from WEBAPI? Is it from code-behind or front-end(with JavaScript)?

Comment: Right now I have no way of retreiving the data from the WEB API, I don't know how to do that.. I'm kind of lost here. 

Should I write the javascript for retreiving the data from the WEB API in the index.cshtml? (Never written any kind of java script before)